# Auto-run Reg Key for the PS Terminal

Tags: windows, powershell

Evening all,

Quick one, hopefully...

In-respect to CMD.exe there is a reg key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor where adding /v autorun and the command it’ll run when launching the application...

Well which is the one for the PowerShell terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one.  Powershell.exe does not provide autorun functionality like cmd.exe does.

Comment: I’ve managed to locate the WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 which I can use.
Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve managed to locate the WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 which I can use.

Thanks for letting me know.